# Tips on controlling fungus gnats

Tags: watering, pests, pest-control

I planted some sweet potato tubers that have been growing vines for a few months now. The plant is potted in the same cactus soil I use for my cactus plant-- very high drainage-- in a tin pot with a dozen drainage holes on the bottom. I water it with about half a cup of water + plant food per week. I feel that this is not too much, but please let me know if it is.

I recently got an infestation of fungus gnats. I didn't realise what it was at first, so unfortunately I didn't start treating until there were about 50-60 (based on the number of adults I've killed with sticky tape/ a makeshift sticky swatter). In summary, I'm catching the adults, I've mixed up the top inch of soil with about a quarter cup of cinnamon, and daily I spray the top of the soil with 3% hydrogen peroxide solution.

Are there any other preventatives measures I can take? I had fungus in the pot about a month ago, which I'm sure lead to this situation, but I water so infrequently I'm not sure what to do about that. Should I start watering it with a <3% hydrogen peroxide solution as opposed to regular filtered water? Not sure if long term that would harm the plant. Also please note that my cactus doesn't have gnats, so I don't think it's a soil quality issue.

Comment: Fun observation-- I've also sprayed the 3% hydrogen peroxide solution on my cactus as a preventative measure. It doesn't foam on the cactus soil, but only when I sprayed the sweet potato soil the first couple of times, which I think is pretty indicative of the problem.

Answer (score 5):

[This site](https://www.smallfootprintfamily.com/how-to-control-fungus-gnats-organically) has some good information on organic control; personally, I prefer the vinegar & sticky traps that they mention. I would use at least one of the methods documented in this site (which you already have - hydrogen peroxide). For clarity for future readers (in case that site goes down), these methods are:

- Reducing the frequency of watering so that the soil dries thoroughly between waterings
- Putting sand on top of the soil (controls larvae)
- Vinegar traps (controls adults)
- Potato traps (controls larvae)
- Homemade or purchased sticky traps (controls adults)
- Diatomaceous earth (controls larvae)
- Watering with a hydrogen peroxide solution (controls larvae)
- Sprinkling cinnamon onto the soil (controls larvae)
- Bt (*Bacillus thuringiensis v. israelensis*) - (controls larvae)
- Beneficial nematodes

So, you have a ton of options, many of which are free or low-cost and some of which you presumably already have in your house.

Comment: I did not know H2O2 could be used here to water.. what about watering with vinegar?

Comment: I wouldn't try watering with vinegar because that will lower the pH in a rather shocking (to the plant) manner. You could use vinegar traps, which won't affect the soil's chemistry.

Answer (score 1):

I have these fungus gnats also often, and especially in indoor plant containers they are a nuisance. Very annoying. When I am fed up with them (i.e. become a pest) I always use a biological control method to get rid of them. It is a treatment with nematodes (*Steinernema feltiae*), which parasite on the larvae of these fungus gnats. You can buy them online, I recently bought them and then the next day they are in the mailbox. You'll have to dissolve them in water and then water your plants with it. Keep the soil a bit moist for a week or two. Coincidentally, I just treated al my plants last week, and now a week later I see only still a few of them flying around. I am sure they'll disappear within another week from now, I have used it before.