# What is the right combination of neem oil and other substances to treat tiny black flies infestation in soil?

Tags: pests, pest-control, toxicity

What is the right combination of neem oil and other substances to treat tiny black flies (fungus gnats, I believe?) infestation in soil?

Answer (score 1):

The tiny black flies in the soil are fungus gnats, so neem oil won't work on them. My answer to [this question](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/55501/tips-on-controlling-fungus-gnats/55503#55503) contains some ways to organically handle these insect sas well as a link to more specific information.